# Select2 and Angular - query function not defined

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 with its angular interface for a select form like

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model='thing' data-placeholder='Options' id='form1>
  <option value=''></Option>
  <option value='1'>Option 1</Option>
  <option value='2'>Option 2</Option>
```

In my controller, I have the line

```
$('#form1').select2();
```

to enable Select2. However, when I run this, I get the error

`query function not defined for Select2 s2id_form1`

and nothing shows up in the input box. I've tried to put in a query function in the initializer, but nothing is working. When I do define a query function, like

```
$('#form1').select2({query: function (query) {return 0;}});
```

It says that I can't put a `query` option in a `select` form. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Well you're bypassing the AngularUI Select2 code by invoking $('#form1').select2() - that's just the regular jQuery select2 method.

You want to setup your select2 options within an object scoped to your controller

```
$scope.select2setup = {...}
```

Then in your html

```
<select ui-select2="select2setup"....>
```

It's all pretty well documented @ https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2